# How to copy assets to build folder in FDT?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, ant, fdt

Flash Builder has an option to "Copy non-embedded files to output folder", which will copy resources loaded at runtime / not compiled into the application from source folders into the `/bin-debug` (build) folder.

How can I do this with FDT? Do I have to use an Ant task? If so -- I'm not familiar with Ant, how would I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Ant's not so hard...the following did the trick:

```
<project default="copy">

<property name="from" value="./assets"/>
<property name="to" value="./bin/assets"/>

<target name="copy">
    <echo message="Copying assets..."/>
    <copy todir="${to}" >
        <fileset dir="${from}"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

And I ran it via a Debug Configuration:

[image]